# Apostrophe and reverse apostrophe in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

If I type `''` (that is, the key directly to the left of the enter/return key 2x) in Helvetica Bold in Photoshop, I get the following:

[image]

However, if I draw this same string in iOS via NSString, I get:

[image]

Is there anyway to get the fancy apostrophes instead of the vertical line ones with an NSString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer XCode, you can include the glyph directly in the `@""` definition.

So: `NSString *test = @"\u2018Hello\u2019";`

In older versions (and in more complex cases), you may find it helpful to use this format:

`NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%CHello%C", 0x2018, 0x2019];`

Check out Wikipedia for a reference to various quoting glyphs and the code points:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *singleQuotes = @"\u2018\u2019";
```

Comment: Should be `NSString *singleQuotes`

Answer (score 1):

When you want unicode characters its usually to display to the user so I use the NSLocalizedString function/macro

for example in code

```
NSString    * message = NSLocalizedString( @"some 'apostrophes'", @"" )
```

and then in the Localizable.strings file I map them to unicode string

```
"some 'apostrophes' " = "some ‘apostrophes’";
```

Comment: Just to add you can then get apostrophes by typing option+] and option+shift+]

Comment: Just be careful not to do that in your source code directly. Odd things can result, even though it will work most of the time.